# How to find pair relationships between rows in a very large table

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table (60m rows) that contains rows with two columns: a set_id and an object_id. The set_id is used to identify groups of object_ids. In my case, those object_ids can appear in multiple sets.

example:

```
set_id | object_id
1 | 100
1 | 101
1 | 102
2 | 100
2 | 201
3 | 300
4 | 102
4 | 300
5 | 500
```

What I need is to retrieve a list of pairs of set_ids that share at least one object_id in common. Each set_id would also be paired with itself. Pairs only show up once (ie: (1,2), but not (2,1)). For the example above:

```
set_id_A | set_id_B
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 4
2 | 2
3 | 3
3 | 4
4 | 4
5 | 5
```

It's fairly simple to write a query to make this happen. The issue is that my solution doesn't scale well. Here is my code:

```
-- #original_sets table created

CREATE TABLE #original_sets
    (
        [set_id] INT,
        [object_id]       BIGINT
    );

-- #original_sets populated here from other data
-- removed

-- index created on table:

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_original_sets
    ON #original_sets ([object_id], [set_id]);

-- code to create the pairs:

            SELECT
                    ck1.[set_id] AS set_id_A,
                    ck2.[set_id] AS set_id_B
            FROM
                    #original_sets ck1
                INNER JOIN
                    #original_sets ck2
                        ON ck1.[object_id] = ck2.[object_id]
                           AND ck1.[set_id] <= ck2.[set_id]
            GROUP BY
                    ck1.[set_id],
                    ck2.[set_id];
```

It's super fast if the original_sets table is small or even medium size, but once I get to 60m rows, it's really slow. I end up canceling it after 10 hours, so I'm not sure if it would ever finish.

A self join on such a large table is just looking for trouble I know. Is there another method to do this that scales better? Thanks!

**Edit 1:** 
Another thing that might help to improve performance: After I get the set pairs I have another process that that then creates super sets that contain all object ids that are related by the original sets (see: transitive closure clustering  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2017/11/12/lateral-thinking-transitive-closure-clustering-with-sql-server-uda-and-json.aspx The diagram at the top shows it nicely)

Because I'm doing that after this, I don't really care about the set_ids themselves, only how they group together the object_ids. So duplicate sets could be eliminated safely. Perhaps doing that first would be a good way to reduce the overall size of the table.

**Edit 2:**

New version to try and reduce the size of original table

```
-- #original_sets table created

CREATE TABLE #original_sets
    (
        [set_id] INT,
        [object_id]       BIGINT
    );

-- #original_sets populated here from other data
-- removed

-- index created on table:

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_original_sets
    ON #original_sets ([object_id], [set_id]);

--added this index:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_original_sets
    ON #original_sets ([set_id], [object_id]);

-- added this part to identify sets with only one object_id 
CREATE TABLE #lonely_sets
(
    [set_id] INT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO #lonely_sets
SELECT  
        [set_id]
    FROM 
        #original_sets
    GROUP BY 
        [set_id]
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) = 1

--then use that data to eliminate duplicate single object sets (see edit 1 for why)

DELETE FROM #original_sets
WHERE set_id IN 
(

SELECT
   [set_id ]
FROM
   #lonely_sets lonely_sets
WHERE
   [set_id ] NOT IN
   (
   SELECT
      MIN(original_sets.[set_id ])
   FROM
      #original_sets original_sets
      INNER join #lonely_sets lonely_sets
        ON original_sets.set_id  =  lonely_sets.set_id 
   GROUP BY
      original_sets.[object_id]
   )

)

-- then run this 
-- code to create the pairs as before:

            SELECT
                    ck1.[set_id] AS set_id_A,
                    ck2.[set_id] AS set_id_B
            FROM
                    #original_sets ck1
                INNER JOIN
                    #original_sets ck2
                        ON ck1.[object_id] = ck2.[object_id]
                           AND ck1.[set_id] <= ck2.[set_id]
            GROUP BY
                    ck1.[set_id],
                    ck2.[set_id];
```

The extra work reduces the original_set down to ~16m rows.
With ~1m unique object_ids and ~7m unique set_ids.

Here is the breakdown of the objects per set:

```
object_count_per_set | sets_with_that_count
67  32
49  8
42  197
41  120
38  1
37  101
35  16
30  23
29  18
28  109
27  1643
26  382
25  43
24  35
23  8
22  492
21  703
20  339
19  1548
18  2176
17  358
16  1156
15  852
14  1755
13  1845
12  2452
11  3073
10  4570
9   4723
8   9726
7   16178
6   35493
5   81091
4   211305
3   724627
2   5360781
1   789573
```

So overall a much smaller table to deal with, but it took just over an hour to finish (1,035,212,815 rows affected), it's still slow to run.

I know there is a lot of duplicate sets that can be safely eliminated, I just need a good method to do so.

Comment: The index on the table is shown above. The 60m rows are all unique as pairs. About 50m unique set_ids and 100k unique object_ids

Comment: Sorry, see comment above (didn't realize that SO posts when you hit return) . Another thing to note is that I expect that trend to continue as the table grows in the future. A lot more sets then objects.

Comment: Do you have a table with only the sets and another with only the objects?

Comment: @stickybit no. I could easily create them if needed though.

Comment: BTW RE: " I end up canceling it after 10 hours" - `sys.dm_exec_query_profiles` can be useful here for determining whether a query is close to completion or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have 60m rows in the table and about 50m unique set_ids and 100k unique object_ids.

So on average each object_id has 600 rows. And on average the `ck1.[object_id] = ck2.[object_id] AND ck1.[set_id] <= ck2.[set_id]` will match 300 rows for each outer row so currently your query is producing and aggregating something in the order of 18 billion rows

The 50 million set ids and 60 million rows means that most sets will only be paired with themselves,

As a first go at this I'd be minded to just find these guaranteed unpaired sets with a simple `GROUP BY ... COUNT` and then exclude them from consideration in the more expensive part with the triangular self join.

If this query is still too slow please provide information about the characteristics of `#paired_sets` in terms of numbers of rows and number of distinct `object_id` and `set_id` as well as size of the largest `object_id` in there (number of rows)

```
CREATE TABLE #lonely_sets
    (
        [set_id] INT PRIMARY KEY
    );

INSERT INTO #lonely_sets
SELECT  [set_id]
FROM #original_sets
GROUP BY [set_id]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;


CREATE TABLE #paired_sets
(
    [set_id] INT,
    [object_id] INT,
    PRIMARY KEY  ([object_id], [set_id])
);

INSERT INTO #paired_sets
SELECT [set_id], [object_id]
FROM #original_sets
WHERE [set_id] NOT IN (SELECT ls.set_id FROM #lonely_sets ls);

--Final Select
SELECT [set_id] AS set_id_A, [set_id] AS set_id_B
FROM #lonely_sets
UNION ALL
SELECT
        ck1.[set_id] AS set_id_A,
        ck2.[set_id] AS set_id_B
FROM
        #paired_sets ck1
    INNER JOIN
        #paired_sets ck2
            ON ck1.[object_id] = ck2.[object_id]
                AND ck1.[set_id] <= ck2.[set_id]
GROUP BY
        ck1.[set_id],
        ck2.[set_id];
```

Comment: but actually this will only prune the really cheap object id to evaluate anyway so wont be much help but the info requested about the characteristics of the paired sets table is useful

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made some edits to my original post to outline what I did and where I'm at now. Also, I gave the wrong number of unique object_ids. It's acutally 1m, not 100k.

Answer (score 0):

So based on suggestions from Martin, I was pointed in the direction of reducing the size of the table being joined, and here is where I ended up:

I decided to attempt to eliminate duplicate sets (see Edit 1 in my original post above).
This should do two things in my case : bring down the size of the table running the self join on later, and help with scaling over time (new sets are introduced weekly, but they are often duplicates of previous sets).

I used the old XML PATH row concatenation trick (I'm not running 2017, otherwise STRING_AGG might work faster?) to create a semi-colon separated list of all object_ids in each set_id.

This is then used to identify set_ids that contain identical sets of object_ids and can therefore be safely eliminated. This reduced the amount of rows from 60m to 1m. This takes about a 50 minutes in my case. Is there a faster way to identify identical sets? I'm not sure.

A filtered table of sets is then created and the relationship table is created based on self joining that. With the new filtered data, the time to run that part of the query is now only a few minutes.

The slowest part of the process is the XML PATH row concat query at just under an hour. That is not ideal, but because this process is part of an emergency maintenance routine, I'm willing to accept the time it takes to run.

Code :

```
-- #original_sets table created

CREATE TABLE #original_sets
    (
        [set_id] INT,
        [object_id]       BIGINT
    );

-- #original_sets populated here from other data
-- removed

-- index created on table:

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_original_sets
    ON #original_sets ([object_id], [set_id]);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_original_sets
    ON #original_sets ([set_id], [object_id]);

----------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE #filtered_sets
    (
        [set_id] INT,
        [object_id]       BIGINT
    );

    INSERT INTO #filtered_sets
    SELECT
         original_sets.set_id,
         original_sets.[object_id]
    FROM
        #original_sets original_sets
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MIN(set_id) AS set_id
            FROM
            (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                            set_id,
                            STUFF(
                                (
                                    SELECT
                                        '; ' +  CAST(original_sets.object_id AS VARCHAR(20))
                                    FROM
                                        #original_sets original_sets 
                                    WHERE
                                        original_sets.set_id = s2.set_id
                                    ORDER BY
                                        original_sets.object_id
                                    FOR XML PATH('')
                                ), 1, 2, ''
                                )                                            AS object_id_list

                    FROM
                            #original_sets s2

                    GROUP BY
                            set_id
            ) a

            GROUP BY
            object_id_list
        ) unique_sets
            ON original_clusters.cluster_id = unique_sets.cluster_id


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_filtered_sets
    ON #filtered_sets ([object_id], [set_id]);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_filtered_sets
    ON #filtered_sets ([set_id],[object_id]);

----------------------------------------------------------
-- then run this 
-- code to create the pairs as before:

            SELECT
                    ck1.[set_id] AS set_id_A,
                    ck2.[set_id] AS set_id_B
            FROM
                    #filtered_sets ck1
                INNER JOIN
                    #filtered_sets  ck2
                        ON ck1.[object_id] = ck2.[object_id]
                           AND ck1.[set_id] <= ck2.[set_id]
            GROUP BY
                    ck1.[set_id],
                    ck2.[set_id];
```

I accepted Martin's answer because it was useful in pointing me where I needed to go. Thanks!